# Windows Azure In-Role Caching Exception issue

Tags: c#, .net, caching, azure, azure-in-role-cache

I am getting this exception :-

> *ErrorCode:SubStatus:There is a temporary failure. Please retry later. (One or more specified cache servers are
>   unavailable, which could be caused by busy network or servers. For
>   on-premises cache clusters, also verify the following conditions.
>   Ensure that security permission has been granted for this client
>   account, and check that the AppFabric Caching Service is allowed
>   through the firewall on all cache hosts. Also the MaxBufferSize on the
>   server must be greater than or equal to the serialized object size
>   sent from the client.). Additional Information : The client was trying
>   to communicate with the server: net.tcp://RoleName:24233.*

I have followed this :- [`Documentation`](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-in-role/) and there are lots of questions and article there but they are little bit old.

Client creation :-

```
 var cacheFactory = new DataCacheFactory();
  _cacheClient = (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cacheName))
                 ? cacheFactory.GetDefaultCache() : cacheFactory.GetCache(cacheName);
```

WebConfig :-

```
<dataCacheClients>
<dataCacheClient name="default" >
       <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="RoleName" />     
</dataCacheClient>
```

**Retry Policy** :- It is inbuild now DataCacheFactory with interval of 1 minute and 60 recount.

I have latest nuget packages like Windows.azure.caching with version 2.5. So does anybody has solved this problem recently. i am quite a stuck here. any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the version of Azure SDK installed? Caching libraries would work with correct versions of SDK.

Comment: I have runtime version - v4.0.30319 version - 2.5.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hit and trial we have found that you should have the latest versions of both `Windows Azure Tools` and `Windows Azure Cache` libraries. What you can do is just install the latest `Windows.Azure.Cache` and then go to you publish azure settings project. Right click go to `Properties => Application` tab then upgrade the `Windows Azure tools` to latest version. And now everything will work like a charm :)

Hope it will save someone else day :)